# How to charge tax via Square Point of Sale API

Tags: square-connect

Is it possible to charge taxes using the square POS API? I want to start a POS transaction from my APP and send a tax percentage to be added with the `ChargeRequest.Builder`.

Example: Customer charges $1.00 using my app and it redirects the customer to the square register app. I want to send a percentage tax along with the ChargeRequest. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot pass a tax with your transaction at this time, but you can set up taxes in the Point of Sale app and and transactions that you create will use that tax. See https://squareup.com/help/us/en/article/5061-modify-your-tax-settings

Comment: I am having issue seeing the taxes sometimes when transaction takes place using pos API. I have created a sales tax in the POS app and set it to applicable to all items. But sometimes when I create a transaction using the POS API, it opens the POS app but don't see any tax added. Sometimes I see the applicable tax added. It happens at a random. We have seen this behavior with different account in different phones (android). Please advice.

Comment: Steps to recreate this issue in an LG android phone:
1. Open the square POS app. Go to tax settings, click on the sales tax and click save.
2. Now close the POS app. (Make sure to close it from the clear all screen).
3. Open an app that uses POS API and create a transaction from there.
4. It will open the square POS app, you shouldn't see the sales tax being added.

I see this behavior every time I follow these steps.

Comment: @FarhadAhmed This was a bug in a recent release of Square POS, sorry about that. We fixed it in a new version that was released two days ago. Would you mind updating Square POS and trying again? Thank you!

Comment: @Pierre-YvesRicau I updated my app but still getting the same error. I am on version 4.77.1

Comment: We reproduced the issue. When the Square POS app was already running, the taxes show-up. When the Square POS app process is started by the POS API request, the taxes are loaded async and don't get applied. We’ve logged the issue and will fix it in a future release. Thank you for helping us identify this issue.